# What does this -ing phrase refer to: "IL17A is produced by Th17 cells, constituting a subtype of T-helper cells"

Tags: participle-phrases

> IL17A is produced mainly by activated Th17 cells, **constituting** a separate subtype of T-helper cells (CD4 +).

Can the participial phrase "constituting a separate subtype of T-helper cells (CD4 +)" refer to "Th17 cells", or does it refer to "IL17A" only?

Comment: Note to myself: [read this](http://languagelog.ldc.upenn.edu/nll/?p=2790)

Comment: Take the red pen to that sentence, being a poor one indeed.

Comment: @TRomano - I actually took, but the translator objected to my comment, and I decided to ask here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Consider these sentences:

> 1a Walking through the meadow, I noticed several orchids.
>   1b I noticed several orchids, walking through the meadow.
>
> 2a Sweeping through the sky, I watched the swallows.
>   2b I watched the swallows, sweeping through the sky.

1a sounds right, but 1b sounds like the orchids were walking through the meadow. 2a sounds like I was sweeping through the sky, but 2b works.

It seems that participial phrases modify the noun that is nearest to them, so in your example it would seem that it modifies Th17 cells.

The moral of the story, then, is "don't use participial phrases unless it's completely clear what they modify."

Comment: Thank you! So it does modify the nearest noun phrase. Is the meaning equal to "IL17A is produced mainly by activated Th17 cells, **which constitute** a separate subtype of T-helper cells (CD4 +)."? Or is it different in some way?

Comment: It seems that in your example the verbs describe prolonged activities, whereas "constitute" is a verb that describes a state.

Comment: @CowperKettle; **Th17 cells** seems to be an abbreviation for **T-helper(type17) cells**, so  the "which constitute" phrasing you suggested looks like a much clearer way of explaining the relationship.

Comment: I was amazed to learn that the ing-phrase refers to "Th17 cells". I was certain that it referred to "interleukin 17A" (IL17A). Live and learn.

Comment: @CowperKettle: I don't think that the fact that **constitute** is stative affects the meaning. **being** is regularly used in participial phrases. "Being English, I..." .

Comment: But this "being" produces a kind of cause-and-effect sense, doesn't it? "[I, being born a woman and distressed by all the needs and notions of my kind, am urged by your propinquity to find your person fair..](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/I,_being_born_a_woman_and_distressed)" I thought that **constituting** might do the same in my example.

Comment: @CowperKettle: In this context, constitute means "Be or be equivalent to (something)". using this definition, "[The Th17 cells] **constitute/are** a separate subtype of T-helper cells (CD4 +)". Meanwhile, at the other end of the sentence, "IL17A **constitutes/is**  a variant of interleukin 17".

Comment: ["The moral of the plot (though I say it, as should not) is: an editor is difficult to suit"](http://www.bartleby.com/104/56.html) ^_^